# Chat unavailable for Verizon network on east coast of USA

Tags: support, chat, maintenance

**The Verizon techs have the link to this post, so please add any information you can here. all additional info is helpful at this point**

Chat seems to be down (requests time out).  Kyle, you broke stuff again!!

Unless my link to the tubes is malfunctioning... Either way, I'm having withdrawals and it's not pretty.

And really, I was going to leave it at that, but apparently that doesn't "meet our quality standards."  What does that even *mean*?

---

This is affecting all services run out of our OR DC. If you are on [Verizon FiOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verizon_FiOS) on the East coast you'll have issues getting to:

- chat
- data.se
- blog.so

-Zypher

---

I've turned this question community wiki. Anyone having issue please do a trace route to `chat.stackexchange.com` and add  the IP/Reverse dns of the router that it dies at below.

Known bad routers:

```
g10-0-8-112.hrbgpa-lcr-01.verizon-gni.net [130.81.184.148]
G0-10-1-1.PHLAPA-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net [130.81.183.18]
g11-0-5-1026.nycmny-lcr-10.verizon-gni.net [130.81.180.4]
L100.WASHDC-VFTTP-125.verizon-gni.net [173.66.170.1]
G0-13-1-5.NYCMNY-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net [130.81.182.78]
g0-2-5-5.nrflva-lcr-21.verizon-gni.net [130.81.140.228]
G0-5-3-1.PHLAPA-LCR-21.verizon-gni.net [130.81.193.192]
G14-0-1-1630.WASHDC-LCR-06.verizon-gni.net (130.81.146.120)
```

Traceroute output if ya got it:

```
  traceroute to chat.stackexchange.com (69.59.196.211), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
1  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home (192.168.1.1)  1.735 ms  0.606 ms  0.545 ms
2  L100.WASHDC-VFTTP-130.verizon-gni.net (96.231.130.1)  7.286 ms  6.926 ms  7.064 ms
3  G14-0-1-1630.WASHDC-LCR-06.verizon-gni.net (130.81.146.120)  8.613 ms !H *  9.221 ms !H

C:\Users\gbeech>tracert chat.stackexchange.com

Tracing route to chat.stackexchange.com [69.59.196.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     8 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.10.10.1
  2     4 ms     4 ms     3 ms  l300.nycmny-vfttp-226.verizon-gni.net [173.56.120.1]
  3  g11-0-5-1026.nycmny-lcr-10.verizon-gni.net [130.81.180.4]  reports: Destination host unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

---

```
Tracing route to chat.stackexchange.com [69.59.196.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     6 ms     5 ms     6 ms  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home [192.168.1.1]
  2    77 ms    53 ms    32 ms  L100.WASHDC-VFTTP-125.verizon-gni.net [173.66.17
0.1]
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4  69.59.196.211  reports: Destination net unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

Comment: I'm having issues too, but the problem seems to be somewhere in the middle. Connecting from my iPhone over 3G works fine, but no luck with my home connection. Good to know it's not just me.

Comment: I guess it's working for the people downvoting this...

Comment: Confirming that it is broken. We're looking into it.

Comment: If you do a trace route does it die at: `g11-0-5-1026.nycmny-lcr-10.verizon-gni.net [130.81.180.4]`

Comment: Good deal guys.  Keep on keepin on.

Comment: @Zypher Mine dies at a Philly equivalent (`G0-10-1-1.PHLAPA-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net [130.81.183.18]`), but yeah.

Comment: I emailed noc@verzion.net . Didn't seem to bounce -- can't find contact info on IANA or whois.

Comment: @Zypher my tracert seems to die on different hops each time.  Not sure what's up...

Comment: @holo you mind posting a couple of the endpoints it dies at?

Comment: @Zypher I'm guessing it dies at endpoints that have ICMP replies turned off, as I have no IPs for them.  The last endpoint I have is `L100.WASHDC-VFTTP-125.verizon-gni.net [173.66.170.1]` and `69.59.196.211  reports: Destination net unreachable.` at the end

Comment: @Zypher and that `L100` endpoint is the next hop after my router...

Comment: Yep looks like it's an outage with their routing on the East cost, anyone in Boston w/ FIOS want to join the party?

Comment: Virginia Fios User, chat's down... I die here g0-2-5-5.nrflva-lcr-21.verizon-gni.net (130.81.140.228)

Comment: @kyle Brandt @Zypher The NOC number for Verizon is 800-243-6994

Comment: @thebeachException - THANKS! that's going in fu_verizon.txt

Comment: Pinged the NOC -- still not resolved. Guess we just have to wait.

Comment: *wimper*  You mean I'll have to work without being able to talk about boobs and stuff?  Oh, the humanity!

Comment: Apparently, old-school Verizon DSL is also affected. At least that's what we have here at work (no FIOS in the borough), and my chat withdrawal is getting exceedingly acute.

Comment: @Marti can you post the last hop DNS and IP when you do a traceroute to chat.stackexchange.com please

Comment: @Zypher: G0-5-3-1.PHLAPA-LCR-21.verizon-gni.net [130.81.193.192]

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Verizon is upgrading Fiber connections on the east coast and this is a side effect. They say it should be resolved in 2-4 hours, around 5AM Eastern Time (US).

Comment: Ah, nice of them to inform us that they were going to break the most important part of the internet. Appreciate the heads up, and since I snuck a nap instead of idling on chat I guess it isn't so bad.

Comment: @Tim You're only slightly wrong.  This is a *travesty*

Comment: @Holocryptic Indeed. It seems Verizon has a *special* interpretation of "2-4 hours."

Comment: Nope still having issues here.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the issue has been fixed.

```
Tracing route to chat.stackexchange.com [69.59.196.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     4 ms     3 ms  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home [192.168.1.1]
  2    20 ms    14 ms    16 ms  L100.WASHDC-VFTTP-125.verizon-gni.net [173.66.17
0.1]
  3    13 ms    25 ms    20 ms  G5-0-5-1725.WASHDC-LCR-07.verizon-gni.net [130.8
1.140.110]
  4    15 ms    13 ms    12 ms  so-12-1-0-0.LCC1-RES-BB-RTR1-RE1.verizon-gni.net
 [130.81.151.230]
  5    20 ms    19 ms    33 ms  0.so-2-3-0.XL3.IAD8.ALTER.NET [152.63.30.17]
  6   115 ms   105 ms   113 ms  0.ge-1-2-0.XT3.POR3.ALTER.NET [152.63.106.33]
  7   102 ms   104 ms   109 ms  GigabitEthernet6-0.GW7.POR3.ALTER.NET [152.63.10
6.54]
  8   102 ms   100 ms   101 ms  noanetoregon-por-gw.customer.alter.net [157.130.
179.94]
  9   101 ms   124 ms   100 ms  vl-12-PTLDORPBCR01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.2
1]
 10   105 ms   103 ms   108 ms  EUGNOR53CR01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.42]
 11   115 ms   111 ms   106 ms  206-192-226-18.lsnetworks.net [206.192.226.18]
 12   110 ms   125 ms   112 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 13   112 ms   131 ms   111 ms  vlan5-cvo-colo2.peak.org [69.59.218.226]
 14   112 ms   105 ms   112 ms  stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.211]

Trace complete.
```

Now I can carry on with the naked drunken debauchery in the privacy of my own home, instead of glancing furtively over my shoulder at work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem:

tracert

```
  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home [192.168.1.1]
  2     4 ms     3 ms     4 ms  L100.NYCMNY-VFTTP-169.verizon-gni.net [71.190.135.1]
  3     *     G0-13-1-5.NYCMNY-LCR-22.verizon-gni.net [130.81.182.78]  reports: Destination net unreachable.
```

Note:  I have Verizon (obv.) and I love me some FIOS, so while this is a sad state right now Verizon does not suck (most of the time.)